# Adding cross-measurement values using Flux query language in grafana

Tags: grafana, influxdb, flux

I have an InfluxDB set up with Flux and want to display a sum the most recent values of two measurements.

The individual values can be displayed via

```
x1 = from(bucket: "telegraf/autogen")
|> range(start: -1h)
|> filter(fn: (r) =>
   r._measurement == "value1")

x1
```

if I attempt to display the sum via

```
x1 = from(bucket: "telegraf/autogen")
|> range(start: -1h)
|> filter(fn: (r) =>
  r._measurement == "value1")

x2 = from(bucket: "telegraf/autogen")
|> range(start: -1h)
|> filter(fn: (r) =>
  r._measurement == "value2")

x1 + x2
```

I get an error. What is the proper way to add the most recent value of measurements?

Answer (score 0):

you managed to got `x1` table and `x2` table, now you join both and add new field with the sum:

```
new_table = join(tables: {x1: x1, x2: x1}, on: ["_time"])
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with "sum_x1_x2": (r._value_x1 + r._value_x2)})
```

The map function allows you to modify/create new values on a table. The result table might have columns "_field", "_measurement", "_value", one for each input table (`x1` and `x2`). Also, the mapped filed "sum_x1_x2" with summed value.

Aggregation / window of data might help as well.